# Store Encrypted Username Hash in Database

Tags: database, security

I'm currently working on basic user authentication for an app I'm putting together, and I don't have much experience with security.

This said, I understand the practice (and necessity) of salting/storing a (salted) password hash in a database as a blob, as opposed to the password (encrypted or no).  I've already implemented this.

Is there anything to be gained by salting/hashing a user name and storing the hash in the database, as opposed to the username in plain-text (or encrypted)?  It strikes me this would make it quite a bit harder to determine which users may access the system using the database for authentication.

Since it's vital to make it difficult for someone to crack the password for a user account, wouldn't it also make sense to increase the difficulty for determining which users are viable?

Edit: it's possible some of the language I'm using isn't 100% correct: feel free to correct :-)

Edit2: I changed one of my first points to indicate salting hashes -- thanks everyone for pointing out that I missed this :-)

Edit3: Removed wording indicating I am encrypting/decrypting a password.  I'm using salted hashes and am storing that in the DB -- thanks Scotty for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short answer:** most likely no.

**Long answer:** Your situation seems to lack the key "my usernames are sensitive because of ..." which raises the question: "Why? What is the specific, demonstrable problem that protecting usernames would solve?"

Without that problem, what you are describing is a common pitfall in security-related development (and really development as a whole): coming up with some idea to secure or obfuscate some part of the system, and then searching for a reason to use it. As with anything in software development, you should avoid doing anything other than exactly what is needed until a clear problem presents itself that can only be solved by using a specific tool.

**Extra hint (for free!):** [salt your password hashes](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000953.html). Plain-old hashes are [far less secure](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000949.html).

Comment: I appreciate your point of contrived obfuscation, but I'm not convinced it applies to my question.  If someone accesses my DB, they would have direct knowledge of user account names.  They might not have immediate knowledge of valid passwords, but isn't it still a security hole?

Comment: @bedwyr it depends on the information built into the usernames and whether the data associated with a given name is sensitive.

Comment: @Rex, I think I get your point: usernames are typically public knowledge (e.g. create a new user, fail, and you now know a user w/that name exists). This piece of information is negligible as long as it's unrelated to any security implementation/execution.  Did I understand correctly?

Comment: Also, thanks for the links.  Every bit of knowledge helps :-)

Comment: @bedwyr or more specifically, your situation seems to lack the key "my usernames are sensitive because of ..." which again raises the question "why? what is the specific, demonstrable problem that protecting usernames would solve?".

Comment: @Rex, this last question is a _great_ one. Unless I can think of a reason the username is specifically sensitive (and if I can, I should probably re-think my implementation), then there's no reason to incur the overhead of salting/hashing/calculating...got it! :-)

Comment: Generally usernames are not considered secure, on computer systems for example the username is always typed in plain text, the password is the one that is to be secured.

Comment: I strongly disagree. I won't downvote because I added my own answer counter to yours. It all depends on the context.

Comment: @EvanPlaice I think we're on the same side - the answer is "Only do something (or don't do something) if you have a specific reason." You also gave some helpful examples.

Comment: Sorry to drudge up an old thread, but let's say one used the username as a salt for the password hash, then would obfuscating the usernames (via hashing with password as salt) be helpful, since you may know a username, but now you can't look at the database and see the hash that goes with that username, making hash tables less useful?

Comment: @EricWolf late follow-up, but short answer: obfuscating a salt doesn't really accomplish much. Salts are to help prevent attacks against the entire user database, not against individual records.

Answer (score 10):

### It depends on the context

It's important to assess the sensitivity of the material you're serving. To dig deeper, I'll provide a few use cases.

**Scenario 1: A social networking application**

All of your user's interactions happen in the public. Their email address will be used as their username. There username is not considered private because their name appears in all their posts. The username may be searched by other users and/or email invites are enabled.

Verdict - Hashing = Bad

**Scenario 2: An E-Commerce site**

The user may or may not participate in public interactions (ex. commenting, reviews). Using an email address as the username is probably a bad idea because, through the use of password recovery, a compromised email account means a compromised user account on your site.

There is a lot of gray area here that is typically exploited for 'convenience.' If your site uses email as the user name, stores shipping history, and credit card numbers; a compromised email could mean a lot of identity theft troubles for your user.

In this case, using a policy where the username **is not** the user's email address is probably a good idea. Hashing the email adds no value.

*Note: I'm looking at you [Amazon.com](http://www.amazon.com/).*

Verdict: Common Practice != good practice

**Scenario 3: A porn site**

Make the username a pseudonym and the login name the user's email address. They may feel inclined to talk about the content and don't necessarily want their name to show up on Google's results for a smut site.

Assume the worst here. If somehow your database is hacked, the exposing of your user's identities could cause irreparable harm. Don't think this could happen to you? [Take a look at this article](http://arstechnica.com/business/news/2012/02/exposed-passwords-in-all-their-plain-text-glory.ars).

Not only are their user's accounts hacked and passwords exposed but, there's a good chance a lot of those users used the same password on their email accounts. Now their info is posted anonymously on PasteBin for the whole world to see. Even worse, most of them probably don't even know this has happened yet.

By simply hashing both the username and password, they would have saved themselves and their users a whole lot of trouble.

Verdict: Definitely hash the email address whether or not it's used as the username.

**Scenario 4: A bank**

It should go without saying that no expense should be spared when it comes to banking/financial sites.

Security can be increased by:

- Using a username other than the email address
- Forcing a unique username by requiring numbers and letters
- Hashing passwords
- Requiring 2-point authentication (in case the user's email password is compromised)
- Hashing email addresses
- etc...

No expense should be spared to protect your users because, to not do so, means you're gambling with their livelihood.

---

**Conclusion:**

There is no hard and fast rule for security that applies to all sites. In some cases, the username is made public so hashing it adds no value. In others, not hashing it could cause irreparable harm. If you do end up developing a site where a username/email hash could be made useful here's a good approach.

1. Hash the username
2. Generate a unique salt for the user
3. Hash the password using the salt
4. Store the password with the salt in the database

By not hashing the username with a salt you avoid the chicken/egg problem. Unless you use a static salt for all of the usernames.

Keep in mind that a static salt for all the user accounts may be found out by reading the code. Once a static salt is found out, it'll essentially be useless when a rainbow table attack is employed. If you salt the passwords, generate a dynamic salt and store it along with the rest of the user's credentials in the database.

**If you want hard/fast rules for simplicity here are a few good assumptions to remember:**

- Assume your database may be compromised at some point
- Assume your source code will be compromised at some point
- Assume your user's email will be compromised at some point
- Assume your user's are dumb and use the same password for your site as they use for their email
- Assume that hackers are smart/resourceful and financially driven.

If you choose to store sensitive/private data, then going the extra step may save you a PR/legal nightmare in the future.

**Update:An interesting article about [seed hashing just showed up on Coding Horror](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html).**

Comment: Good answer. There are lots of times where simply knowing that 'razer9898' is registered on a certain website IS a huge security breach. Apologies to any razers out there.

Comment: @TomAndersen Most definitely. Just look at the accounts of the latest user database breaches. LinkedIn, eHarmony, even Blog Overflow had one because of a tainted WP theme. Usernames aren't sensitive but if a breach means that you're forking over millions of usernames in a structured format, you're doing your userbase an even greater disservice.

Comment: Note: For security reasons I will no longer be using my real name as my handle and from here on out will be referred to as 'he who shall not be named'.

Answer (score 4):

If you salted & hashed the username, you'd leave yourself with a bit of a chicken & egg problem.

If you salted & hashed the username, how would you find it in the database?  You'd need to look up the user's record to find the salt you used to hash the username...

Comment: What if you used the password as a salt for the username and the username as a salt for the password? When someone logs in, the database is searched for saltedUser with password saltedPass

Answer (score 1):

Probably not.  Think of it this way - the username is the application's way of figuring out which account a user is trying to login as.  The password is the application's way of figuring out whether the user is actually allowed to login as that account.  In practice, this means you're going to look up a row in your accounts table using the username as an index. By encrypting the username, you're simply making it harder to find the right row.

However, if you're using the same encryption scheme to encrypt the username and password, they are pretty much equally secure - if you can break one, you can break the other.  Thus, encrypting both makes it harder to lookup the user, but doesn't add any additional security.

**Note:** In your question you talk about decrypting your password field.  You probably want to make this impossible (literally).  Most people encrypt their passwords using a one-way hash function of some sort (MD5 and SHA256 are popular), along with a salt.  The "one-way" part simply means that once you run something through the function, you can't use what you get out to get what you started with.  However, if you start with the same input, you'll always get the same output.  The salt is a secret that only your application knows (sort of like an encryption key), which is added to whatever you are encrypting, before it is run through the one-way hash.  This makes it impossible to do things like match two encrypted passwords from two different sites (assuming they're using different salts).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts: hashing a username does make it harder (and thus more costly) to lookup a user account.  Would using different salts address your second point (e.g. break one your break the other)?

Comment: Not really.  Salting the password (which you do anyway) will make the authentication part of the lookup much harder, and then we're back to point one...

Comment: ...salting the username too gives the hacker twice as much work to do, but that's irrelevant.  If they spent 10 hours on the password they can spend 10 hours on the username; if they need to spend 100 years on the password they won't even get to the username.

Comment: @Scotty, thanks for your 'Note'; I updated my question.  I'm salting the hash and storing the result, and then running the encryption/salt algorithm on the inputted password to see if the result is the same.

Comment: @NikhilChelliah "they are pretty much equally secure," I disagree. Using a static salt on the username means a brute force will only take longer if the site's source code hasn't been compromised. Using a dynamic hash on the password will make a brute force take exponentially longer as long as the database remains secure because the password's salt will be different for each user.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very fair to your users to store their password in plain text since everybody that has access to your database can see their passwords. You should use a salted hash.

[Salt_(cryptography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))

Comment: As I mentioned, I understand storing a password hash (I didn't mention a salt, but I figured it was understood) as opposed to plain text.  My question is concerning _usernames_.

Answer (score 0):

You can never properly evaluate the security of a system by looking at a single part of it in isolation. Whereabouts are you storing the key to decrypt the passwords?

Do the people that have access to the database also have access to the location you are storing the encyption key? If so you've only gained a minor improvement in security by encrypting the passwords and probably nothing much more to gain by encrypting the usernames.

If the decryption key and program using it are more secure than the database - which is pretty unusual, normally the database is in the most secure spot possible - then there would possibly be additional benefit to also encrypting the username as you'd be depriving attackers of useful information in brute force attacks.